Is there a way to get the viewsContainers active activitybar?
I have defined my own activity view
"viewsContainers": {
            "activitybar": [
                {
                    "id": "foo",
                    "title": "Foo",
                    "icon": "$(foo)"
                }
            ]
        },

From the extension activation side I want to check whether the current activity view is visible or has been clicked by user.
So far didnt find a way to do that

Is your View a treeView?
